# Interpolated data not updating

Tags: angular, typescript, onchange

I have data that is suppose to get updated when I flip a toggle.
The returned data is then interpolated into the component.

I am currently using Markdown https://github.com/dimpu/angular2-markdown
The code looks like this in the html file:

```
<markdown>{{post?.text}}</markdown>
```

The toggle:

```
    onChange(value: any) {
        if (value.checked === true) {
          this.areaService.isAreaChecked = true;
          this.areaService.currentAreaName = 'information';
        } else {
          this.areaService.isAreaChecked = false;
          this.areaService.currentAreaName = 'fun';
        }

        this.postService.getNextPost(this.areaService.currentAreaName)
          .subscribe((post: Post) => {
            this.post = post;
            if (post) {
              this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net/areas/' + this.areaService.currentAreaName + '/' + post.id;
            } else {
              this.text = 'https://client.wildfyre.net';
            }
          });

          this.areaService.getAreaRep(this.areaService.currentAreaName)
            .subscribe(reputation => {
              this.rep = reputation;
            });
      }
```

The problem is that when the post.text is suppose to update it does not.
It keeps the same data as it had before
Is there anyway I can force it to redo the methods in `<markdown>`? Similar to a ngOnit

When I remove the markdown tags it works perfectly

Comment: Does `postService.getNextPost(...)` call out to non-Angular code? Try injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` after modifying `this.post`

Comment: It calls out to an angular service, get an error -> Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

Comment: An angular service is still angular code. With injecting I meant `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}`. If you don't call out to non-Angular code, this shouln't be necessary though.

Comment: Was able to solve this problem by using a different package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-markdown-to-html